# SQL Server 2008 - How to display only certain tables (Restrictions on where clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following script

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000);
DECLARE @tableName sysname; 
DECLARE @columnName sysname;

DECLARE theCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE
      DATA_TYPE = 'date' or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'

OPEN theCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TabelName], ' + 
               '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' +
               'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + 
               ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
               ' GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC (@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;
END

CLOSE theCursor
DEALLOCATE theCursor;
```

However there two problems with this code.

1. The result is a list of tables, however I don't want any of these tables to have `_` symbol in them. I have tried `WHERE TABLE_NAME not like '%_%'` but that doesn't seem to get rid of all the tables with `_` in it.
2. The result displays a list of tables with some having no rows (because there is no result). How do I emit these tables from not showing in the results window, and only the tables that have rows show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Your first problem occurs because `_` is a wildcard character that means a single letter in sql server.

For example, if you wanted to search for only single character words you'd use `like '_'`  Putting square braces around the underscore will escape it, so your query would be:

```
WHERE 
  (DATA_TYPE = 'date' or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
  and TABLE_NAME not like '%[_]%'
```

2) In order to stop the tables without rows from showing, I would use a `Having`.

```
'GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')' +
'Having Count(*) > 0'
```

This will only show tables that have one or more rows.

EDIT:

After a bit of conversation, it was revealed that the cursor should be restricted to only results with rows, not the exec'd query.

I added a test to see if there were any rows in your tables.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000);
DECLARE @tableName sysname; 
DECLARE @columnName sysname;
DECLARE @count int;
DECLARE theCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE
      (DATA_TYPE = 'date' or DATA_TYPE = 'datetime')
      and table_name not like '%[_]%'

OPEN theCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT count(*) as cnt into ##temp_count FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
    EXEC (@sql);
    select @count = cnt from ##temp_count
    drop table ##temp_count
    if(@count > 0)
    begin
      SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @tableName + ''' as [TabelName], ' + 
                 '''' + @columnName + ''' AS [ColumnName], ' +
                 'DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + 
                 ') AS [Year], COUNT(1) AS [NumberofRows] FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + 
                 ' GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ')';
      PRINT @sql;
      EXEC (@sql);
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM theCursor INTO @tableName, @columnName;
END

CLOSE theCursor
DEALLOCATE theCursor;
```

Comment: Hi I tried both of those but none of them seemed to work. It still showed the same number of tables in results that had _ in them. And the Having count did not have an effect either

Comment: @user3712641 post the output of your sql, lets take a look.

Comment: The output of my sql query just gives this,

Table Name  Column Name  Year  NumberofRows

With nothing under it (i.e no rows)

And this happens with some of the tables that show up (which is my second problem, and I am trying to remove them)

Comment: I'm running the underscore query on my box and it works perfectly.  I see where I misunderstood with the having however.  You need to test to see if there is a count, then run the sql.. so its as if you need to run it twice.

Comment: I seem to have found the problem to #1. I'm using 2 where conditions. One is where data type is this, and other is where name is not this. However when I comment out the data type part it works fine. Is there a way to have both where conditions, did I write it wrong?

Comment: I figured out number one, your brackets did work, just for some reason sql wanted the where clauses to be switched. As in the name part comes first, then the data part. And could you pleas elaborate about " I see where I misunderstood with the having however. You need to test to see if there is a count, then run the sql.. so its as if you need to run it twice."

Comment: What you are getting is `this` or `that` and `thus`.  So if `this` is true you'll get a hit or if `that and thus` is true you'll get a hit.  What you want is (`this` or `that`) and `thus`, so that it evaluates the first section as one.

Comment: To elaborate on #2, you want to execute the sql, see if there are any rows returned, then execute that sql if they are.  So really, you'd want this as a subselect of your cursor.

Comment: Would you mind looking at my code above and changing this so I can see what you mean? I'm not too advanced at SQL so I don't still fully understand cursors yet, the code above was mainly given to me.

Comment: @user3712641, check out my edit, i added a test, so only tables with rows show up.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much